# I already have a complete HTML/CSS mockup should I use a base theme or start from scratch?

Tags: theming

Will it be less painful to just build my theme from scratch using the HTML/CSS mockup that I have or should I still go through the process of using a base theme like Zen?

Comment: Sorry, but I have to close this.  It is really halfway between too broad and primarily opinion-based.

Comment: It's unfortunate because I think it's a valid question...especially for those relatively new to Drupal. I've been working with Drupal for 3yrs+ and still don't know what the best approach is given a complete HTML/CSS mockup.

Comment: We can discuss this on Meta if you want; just post a question there.

Answer (score 2):

It's a mix of personal preference, familiarity with the theme system and, arguably most importantly, the experience of the end-user admin and how much they'll need to modify layout.

Unless the site layout will need to be extensively modified (by a non-developer, beyond just toggling/placing blocks) I would always choose to start from scratch.